# Why is Sakurai-sensei always sweating like a sprinkler?

Tags: nichijou

I never really figured this out. Is Sakurai-sensei always super-uncomfortable around people? Or is she nervous? Usually sweat drops jumping off someone is a vfx for surprise, but I don't think this is the case.

[image] [image]

What's up with those crazy sweat drop novas all the time?

Comment: I just LOLed at your title, 'sprinkler' +1 for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably just an exaggeration of her being nervous and/or shy. As her personality bio on the [Nichijou Wikia](http://nichijou.wikia.com/wiki/Izumi_Sakurai) says, "Izumi is a very nice young woman, but she is usually very shy, flustered, and easily frightened."

This is similar to the [Overly Nervous Flop Sweat](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OverlyNervousFlopSweat) trope, though that page doesn't have a section for anime or manga.

Some other instances of this:

Danganronpa:

[image]

Chii:

[image]

Kero:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

No matter who Sakurai-sensei is talking to (other teachers, students, etc) she has those panic bubbles/sweat drops around her.

I took this to mean she's just a naturally nervous person instead of being uncomfortable around people. I can't think of anything in the show that implied she was uncomfortable around others since she was always willing to help and talk.